# Conditional editing in gxt grid

Tags: gxt

I have an editable gxt tree grid, now the problem is only certain rows has to be editable.
after some goggling I was able to find this stuff. I am using the inline editor

```
editing.addBeforeStartEditHandler(new BeforeStartEditHandler<RevenueGrossBean>() {

            @Override
            public void onBeforeStartEdit(
                    BeforeStartEditEvent<RevenueGrossBean> event) {

                                                    //how to acess the model bean that is about to be edited
                                               //hw to prevent the edit action from completion

            }
        });
```

IS there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure it is going to work but to access the model bean that is about to be edited you can try something like this: `yourGridStore.get(event.getEditCell().getRow());`

Comment: @RadASM the logic would have worked fine for plain grid, since this is a tree grid we cant rely on 'event.getEditCell().getRow()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can be achieved using selection model

```
 editing.addBeforeStartEditHandler(new BeforeStartEditHandler<RevenueGrossBean>() {

                @Override
                public void onBeforeStartEdit(
                        BeforeStartEditEvent<RevenueGrossBean> event) {

            //how to acess the model bean that is about to be edited
           RevenueGrossBean bean = event.getSource().getEditableGrid()
                        .getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
           //hw to prevent the edit action from completion
           event.setCancelled(true);



                }
            });
```

Comment: That approach is a bit insecure because that depends on if the user did select a row literally,  but you will find a bug if the user instead of a click he or she navigates the grid with the tab key, you will get a different result. You can  use: YourBean = event.getSource().getEditableGrid().getStore().get(event.getEditCell().getRow()) with better results.